# Unit tests producing different results when using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, phpunit, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

Been working on a module that is working pretty well when using MySQL, but when I try and run the unit tests I get an error when testing under PostgreSQL (using Travis).

The module itself is here: https://github.com/silvercommerce/taxable-currency

An example failed build is here: https://travis-ci.org/silvercommerce/taxable-currency/jobs/546838724

I don't have a huge amount of experience using PostgreSQL, but I am not really sure why this might be happening? The only thing I could think that might cause this is that I am trying to manually set the ID's in my fixtures file and maybe PostgreSQL not support this?

If this is not the case, does anyone have an idea what might be causing this issue?

Edit: I have looked again into this and the errors appear to be because of [this assertion](https://github.com/silvercommerce/taxable-currency/blob/1.0/tests/TaxableCurrencyTest.php#L88), which should be finding the Tax Rate [vat](https://github.com/silvercommerce/taxable-currency/blob/1.0/tests/TaxableCurrencyTest.yml#L7) but instead finds the Tax Rate [reduced](https://github.com/silvercommerce/taxable-currency/blob/1.0/tests/TaxableCurrencyTest.yml#L12)

I am guessing there is an issue in my logic that is causing the incorrect rate to be returned, though I am unsure why...

Comment: What results are you getting that are different than what is expected? And what statements are giving you those results?

Comment: Added an edit with some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end it appears that Postgres has different default sorting to MySQL (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-order.html). The line of interest is:

*The actual order in that case will depend on the scan and join plan types and the order on disk, but it must not be relied on*

In the end I didn't really need to test a list with multiple items, so instead I just removed the additional items.

If you are working on something that needs to support MySQL and Postgres though, you might need to consider defining a consistent sort order as part of your query.

Comment: We occasionally run into sorting inconsistencies with PGSQL in SilverStripe's supported modules, and often abstract the assertions a little so that the order of the items doesn't matter. Most of the time you can leave sorting to the DB engine and skip testing it.

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much what I did, Order wasn't important for this particular test. Cheers for the clarification @RobbieAverill